# Debugging an error: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly

Tags: php, theme-development, functions, debug

I've just uploaded a new, custom theme to find that the container is a fraction of the intended width, and the sections below the home section(this is one single page, long site utilizing ids/anchors to navigate) are no longer showing.
I turned on DEBUG to see if I could spot the problem, and after deactivating problematic plugins, I'm left with this error:

> Notice: `wp_enqueue_style` was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in `/home/achenn/public_html/frshstudio.com/wp-includes/functions.php` on line 2959

Problem is, the only thing on that particular line is:

```
trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
```

I've seen other [blog posts](http://www.matthewbredel.com/1673/wp-plugin-error-wp_enqueue_style-was-called-incorrectly.html) and forums, but the line they are telling me to search for is non-existent in this file, much less on the given line.

Any tips, ideas, etc on how to remedy this challenge are greatly appreciated.

[image: phrase in question is not in file]

[Live site.](http://frshstudio.com/)

Comment: I bet it has something to do with the error at the top of the page:

     Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/achenn/public_html/frshstudio.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2959

Of course, turning the maint. mode plugin off might help as well...:)

Comment: @jfacemyer Yeah, I just noticed that error as well. Maint Mode is now off(thought, I did that before, sorry). 

I turned off all plugins causing trouble, and am left with the error you mentioned. Problem is, I can't find that line of code anywhere, much less in the specified file on the specified line.

Comment: [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) your theme and plugin directories for `wp_enqueue_script`. It can't be that hard to find.

Comment: @s_ha_dum as mentioned below, scanned a few files and did a specific search for `wp_enqueue_style` and `enqueue`, nothing found.

Comment: Don't "scan a few files". Search the whole `wp-content` directory. Given that the error references `wp_enqueue_style`, it has to be there. The problem _is not in_ `/wp-includes/functions.php`. Sometimes the error messages mislead.

Answer (score 9):

In other words, you should not perform a [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) which is not hooked to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

Your `wp_enqueue_style` should be in a function, and you should hook that function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` like in the following example:

```
function wpse88755_enqueue(){
  # call  wp_enqueue_style here
}

#hook the function to wp_enqueue_scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse88755_enqueue' );
```

Comment: I understand the concept, and I appreciate your time and answer. My problem is, I can't find `wp_enqueue_style` in any of my `wp-includes` files.

Comment: You should check it in your theme folder. It is the notice that is being triggered from `/wp-includes/functions.php`. This folder contains core WordPress files.

Comment: Checked that file, did a specific search for `wp_enqueue_style` and `enqueue`, nothing found.

Comment: which file you checked? Check the folder of you current theme - `wp-content/themes/your-theme`

Comment: I've checked EVERY file in my current theme folder, EVERY file in wp-includes(found `wp_enqueue_style` in `class-wp-admin-bar.php`, `class-wp-customize-control.php`, `class-wp-editor.php`, `functions.wp-styles.php`, `general-template.php`, `and media.php` BUT nothing looked out of the ordinary, and I don't know how to proceed further with checking.

I appreciate your efforts with this.

Comment: Unless you've edited the core, you shouldn't be looking in wp-includes. You should be looking in any plugins you have activated and your current theme (including any possible parent theme).

If you can't find it in the current theme, try activating a different one to see if it gives you the same error. If so, you've got something going on in a different place (probably a plugin). Then, try deactivating each plugin to see where the problem will be.